# Resizing partitions; more Linux and less Windows

Tags: linux, hard-drive, partitioning, arch-linux

When I installed Linux I was afraid to change to it completely, so I gave it only 50.1 Gb, while Windows got 180 GB. Now this is not enough for Linux, and I want to "take" some space from Windows and give it to Linux.

Here is my partition layout: ( from cfdisk )

```
/dev/sda1                   *                                     1126400               378613759               377487360                  180G                7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda2                   *                                   378613760               383422463                 4808704                  2,3G               83 Linux
/dev/sda3                                                       383422464               488397167               104974704                 50,1G               83 Linux
```

/dev/sda1 - NTFS for Windows

/dev/sda2 - swap

/dev/sda3 - ext4 with Linux and GRUB

1. Is the correct method to reduce first sda1, then increase sda2, then decrease sda2, and finally increase sda3?
2. Will I not destroy the data on the disk in this way?
3. Will GRUB on the sda3 partition still boot and give me the choice of Linux and Windows?

Comment: Linux antoni 5.3.1-arch1-1-ARCH #1 SMP PREEMPT Sat Sep 21 11:33:49 UTC 2019 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Comment: There is no need to preserve the data on the swap space. You can simplify it a bit and save some time by turning swap off, deleting the swap drive, move and resize sda3 and recreate the swap at the end of the drive.

Comment: I’d recommend to use a [bootable Linux with GParted](https://gparted.org/liveusb.php ) to do this. This prevents mount locks and gives a good visual representation of what you’re doing.

Comment: Do you use hibernation? Please answer by clicking [edit] and putting that in your question. Please do not use Add Comment.

Answer (score 0):

0 Boot from a Linux LIVEUSB so you can resize both the ext4 and NTFS partitions.
1 Pending answer regarding use of hibernation.
2 You won't destroy your data if done precisely, but always back up your data before any partition changes.
3 Yes.

Comment: So, how to do it precisely?